# C++ Undefined reference when using class member in constructor

Tags: c++, variables, constructor, ros

I am pretty new to C++, so the question might sound stupid, but even though I googled quite some time, I could not find an answer. I am using the ROS environment, but my question should be a general C++ problem, so I decided to post it here.

I have two codes

1)

```
ros::Duration max_storage_time = ros::Duration().fromNSec(1ULL * 1000000000LL);
tf::TimeCache odometryCache(max_storage_time);
```

2)

```
tf::TimeCache odometryCache(ros::Duration max_storage_time = ros::Duration().fromNSec(1ULL * 1000000000LL));
```

The second one compiles, while the first one does not. To me, the seem to be exactly the same. The error for the first code is: 
undefined reference to `tf::TimeCache::TimeCache(ros::Duration)`

The documentation of tf::TimeCache can be found at http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1TimeCache.html#acca87a70aeb9c3573cdbfec26f6bfe23

Could somebody please tell me what I am missing? Where is the difference between the code pieces and why does the first one not compile?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do in the constructor call when you do `ros::Duration max_storage_time = ros::Duration().fromNSec(1ULL * 1000000000LL)`?  Did you man to copy the `ros::Duration max_storage_time = ` part?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, the second one (using only one line) works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not linking properly with the ROS libraries.
The solution is to set up your linker properly.

Only the first one actually calls any ROS functions - the second declares a function that takes a `ros::Duration` and returns a `tf::TimeCache` (This is called "the most vexing parse").

If you never try to use `odometryCache`, the second will not cause any problems.
If you do (for instance, `odometryCache.clearList()`) the compiler will complain that you're trying to access a member of a non-aggregate type, or something along those lines.

If you don't try to name the constructor's argument:

```
tf::TimeCache odometryCache(ros::Duration().fromNSec(1ULL * 1000000000LL));
```

it will compile, but linking will fail just like for the first piece.

Answer (score 3):

`tf::TimeCache odometryCache(ros::Duration max_storage_time = ros::Duration().fromNSec(1ULL * 1000000000LL));`

This is declaration of function `odometryCache`, not call to constructor of `tf::TimeCache`. This is called "Most vexing parse" in C++.

Correct fix here would be simple:

`tf::TimeCache odometryCache(ros::Duration().fromNSec(1ULL * 1000000000LL))`

or, if C++11 is available:

`tf::TimeCache odometryCache{ ros::Duration().fromNSec(1ULL * 1000000000LL) }`

Comment: Sorry, but neither of your options compile, while this version of my code is compiling

Comment: As said in another answer, the problem was within the linking to ROS, so your answer was correct, too